# Proxy Pattern in iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsproxy

I need to create proxy pattern in iOS using swift

I have tried it using Objective C and here is the code

**MyProtocol.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@required
-(void)testMessage;    
@end
```

**TestBO.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface TestBO : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@end
```

**TestBO.m**

```
#import "TestBO.h"

@implementation TestBO 

-(void)testMessage{
    NSLog(@"Test Message");
}

@end
```

**TestProxyHandler.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestProxyHandler : NSProxy

@property (nonatomic, strong) id object;

- (instancetype)initWithProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol andObject:(Class)clazz;

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation;

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector;

@end
```

**TestProxyHandler.m**

```
#import "TestProxyHandler.h"
#import "TestBO.h"

@implementation TestProxyHandler 

- (instancetype)initWithProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol andObject:(Class)clazz{
    if ([clazz conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]) {
        self.object = [[clazz alloc] init];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error it does not conform to protocol");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation{
    NSString *selString = NSStringFromSelector(invocation.selector);
    NSLog(@"Called %@",selString);
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:self.object];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    return [self.object methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
}


@end
```

I have invoked it using

```
id <MyProtocol> delegate = (TestBO *)[[TestProxyHandler alloc] initWithProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol) andObject:[TestBO class]];

[delegate testMessage];
```

But I am not able to make it work in Swift even the initialzier is showing that the message

**TestHandler.swift**

```
import Foundation
class TestHandler: NSProxy {
    var object: AnyObject

    convenience override init(`protocol`: Protocol, andObject clazz: AnyClass) {
        if clazz.conformsToProtocol() {
            self.object = clazz()
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Error it does not conform to protocol")
        }
    }        
}
```

Does anyone have any clue to do this in swift ??

**EDIT:**

In [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) you can create runtime implementation of a method using the **Proxy.newProxyInstance** call but can this be achieved in iOS ? using swift ? Any clue ?

Comment: ya ? so keywords can be used if specified with ` sign, anyway did try renaming ti too but still doesnt work

Comment: Have you found a solution? If so, I would be very thankful, if you can provide it.

Comment: @Ruben : Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing with Objective C and Swift, Swift offers extremely limited access to runtime language access . So based on my research till now it can’t be done :(

I even tried subclassing the *NSProxy* class in swift but just couldn’t call the *super.init* and code never compiles but however same thing works in objective C

So I ended up doing this approach

I created a protocol using

```
@objc protocol SomeProt {
    // Some method
}
```

Note the keyword **@objc**  before protocol is essential else you would not be able to pass it as a variable, also adding **@objc** limits the usage of protocol to objective c runtime features so don’t expect to get full features of protocols in swift

```
public func someMethod(`protocol` : Protocol, implementation : AnyClass) {
    let isImplemented : Bool = implementation.conformsToProtocol(`protocol`)
        // some code
}
```

If you need to use it in some dictionary or places where it should conform to *NSCopying* class then use

> NSStringFromProtocol

and

> NSProtocolFromString

methods

Now I have wrote a objective c helper class to do the initialization

**ObjcHelper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjcHelper : NSObject
+(NSObject *)objectForClass:(Class)clazz;
@end
```

**ObjcHelper.m**

```
#import "ObjcHelper.h"

@implementation ObjcHelper
+ (NSObject *)objectForClass:(Class)clazz{
    return [[clazz alloc] init];
}
@end
```

Now to use it

```
let prot : SomeProt = ObjcHelper.objectForClass(NSClassFromString("PROT_HANDLER_CLASS_NAME")) as! SomeProt
```

However in future if anyone can offer a better answer then please be sure to post it here